# error parsing json into MS access tables using VBA

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, parsing

Please see code below for parsing data from json into MS Access tables using VBA. The first level (Order) works fine, it's the second level (OrderLine) that is getting an error, and not quite sure how to get the OrderDetailID (which is an auto-number) from the first table into the second table to be able to link. I have been using some code i found online and replicated but something not quite right. I'm using the Tim Hall VBA-json parser.
First error is Data type conversion error on line rs!OrderDetailID = Order("OrderID"). If i leave that line out then i get error Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on line arrValues = Split(OrderLine, ",").
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Json data retrieved:

```
{"Order":
[{"ShipLastName":"Bloggs",
"ShipFirstName":"Joe",
"OrderID":"INV1324",
"OrderType":"sales",
"OrderLine":
    [{"Quantity":"1",
    "SKU":"9045200017",
    "OrderLineID":"INV1324-0"}],
"DeliveryInstruction":"",
"ShipPhone":"+6491234567",
"Email":"joe.bloggs@somecompany.com",
"ShippingOption":"Standard Shipping",
"ShipCompany":"Some Company Ltd",
"ShipStreetLine1":"58 Some Street",
"ShipCity":"Some City",
"ShipState":"Some State",
"ShipCountry":"NZ",
"CustomerRef1":"",
"DatePlaced":"2021-06-03 22:26:48",
"OrderStatus":"Pick",
"ShipPostCode":"2103"}],
"CurrentTime":"2021-09-21 05:10:24",
"Ack":"Success"}
```

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit
    Dim arrValues() As String
    Dim I As Integer
    --------------------------
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim JsonText As Object
    Dim Order As Variant
    Dim OrderLine As Variant

    'add order to tblOrderDetails
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblOrderDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    Set JsonText = JsonConverter.ParseJson(reader.responseText)
   
    For Each Order In JsonText("Order")
        rs.AddNew
        rs!Date = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        rs!Time = Format(Now(), "hh:nn")
        rs!ClientID = 123
        rs!OrderNo = Order("OrderID")
        rs!DelPhone = Order("ShipPhone")
        rs!NotifyEmailAddress = Order("Email")
        rs!DelName = Order("ShipCompany")
        rs!DelStreet = Order("ShipStreetLine1")
        rs!DelSuburb = Order("ShipCity")
        rs!DelCity = Order("ShipState")
        rs!DelZipCode = Order("ShipPostCode")
        rs!DelCountryID = DLookup("CountryID", "tblCountries", "CountryCode = '" & Order("ShipCountry") & "'")
        rs!DelContactName = Order("ShipFirstName") & " " & Order("ShipLastName")
        rs.Update
    Next Order
    
    'add products to tblOrdersProd
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblOrdersProd", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    
    Set JsonText = JsonConverter.ParseJson(reader.responseText)
        
    For Each Order In JsonText("Order")
        For Each OrderLine In Order("OrderLine")
          rs.AddNew
          rs!OrderDetailID = Order("OrderID")
          arrValues = Split(OrderLine, ",")
          For I = 0 To UBound(arrValues)
             rs!Qty = arrValues(1)
             rs!Productid = DLookup("ProductID", "tblProducts", "ProductCode = '" & OrderLine(arrValues(2)) & "'")
          Next
          rs.Update
       Next OrderLine
    Next Order
    rs.Close
```

Comment: If `OrderDetailID` is an autonumber field then you can't set it using insert. Perhaps you need to change the data type of the field to integer so that it can be written to.

Comment: Re the second error, I can see that OrderLine is not a string value but an array structure object within the Order JSON, so trying to split it gives an error.

Comment: The OrderDetailID is an auto-number in the tblOrderDetails table, it is just a number field in the tblOrdersProd table, but that's the field that links the tables. One of the issues is trying to get that ID from the record that has been created in tblOrderDetails to be able to use in tblOrdersProd in the 2nd level of parsing. Thx

Comment: Then I am puzzled by why you are setting `tblOrdersProd!OrderDetailID` to Order("OrderID") which is not the autonumber field.  You will need to add logic to the earlier insert into the tblOrderDetails to get the assigned autonumber id, then use that id when inserting into tblOrdersProd.

Comment: One suggestion that I have is to use a GUID field instead of autonumber, then you can create the GUID for each row inserted, and use that as the link. But maybe you are restricted by your existing database design?

Comment: I was following the code that someone else had written, replacing names where applicable. It seemed to work in the application i was copying the code from. I have a work around for that, main issue is the 2nd part, getting the 2nd level of the parsing. Thx

Comment: The object OrderLine in order is an array of objects, so in your ForEach loop you should be able to code `rs!OrderDetailID = Order("OrderID"): rs!Qty=OrderLine("Quantity"): rs!Productid = DLookup("ProductID", "tblProducts", "ProductCode = '" & OrderLine("SKU") & "'")` or something like that - warning I cannot test this

Comment: Why have you coded the second part by reparsing the JSON? Can't you put the second-level code within the loop for the top level, and avoid two loops round all the orders?

Comment: I was thinking about putting within first loop, but again was just using code already supplied which worked how it was within that application. Just not sure of the coding. The whole parsing json is new to me, just working through it bit by bit trying to make it work for what i need. Thx

Comment: when using a recordset like rs and calling AddNew the easiest way to get the new record's Primary Key which should be an Autonumber is to grab it before calling rs.Update.    So something like dim CurrentOrderId as integer, rs.AddNew, CurrentOrderDetailID = rs("OrderDetailID"), rs.Update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, you may need to adjust a bit to get it working...

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'//--------------------------
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsOrderDetails As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsOrdersProd As DAO.Recordset
Dim JsonText As Object
Dim Order As Variant
Dim OrderLine As Variant
Dim newID as Long

'add order to tblOrderDetails
Set rsOrderDetails = db.OpenRecordset("tblOrderDetails", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

'add products to tblOrdersProd
Set rsOrdersProd = db.OpenRecordset("tblOrdersProd", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)


Set JsonText = JsonConverter.ParseJson(reader.responseText)

For Each Order In JsonText("Order")
    With rsOrderDetails
        .AddNew
        !Date = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        !Time = Format(Now(), "hh:nn")
        !ClientID = 123
        !OrderNo = Order("OrderID")
        !DelPhone = Order("ShipPhone")
        !NotifyEmailAddress = Order("Email")
        !DelName = Order("ShipCompany")
        !DelStreet = Order("ShipStreetLine1")
        !DelSuburb = Order("ShipCity")
        !DelCity = Order("ShipState")
        !DelZipCode = Order("ShipPostCode")
        !DelCountryID = DLookup("CountryID", "tblCountries", "CountryCode = '" & Order("ShipCountry") & "'")
        !DelContactName = Order("ShipFirstName") & " " & Order("ShipLastName")
        .Update

        '// Now get the newly-allocated autonumber field
        .Bookmark = .LastModified 
        newID = !OrderDetailID
    End With

    For Each OrderLine In Order("OrderLine")
      With rsOrdersProd
          .AddNew

          '// Use the ID from the OrderDetails record
          !OrderDetailID = newID
     
          !Qty = OrderLine("Quantity")
          !Productid = DLookup("ProductID", "tblProducts", "ProductCode = '" & OrderLine("SKU") & "'")
    
          .Update
      End With
    Next OrderLine

    
Next Order

rsOrderDetails.Close
rsOrdersProd.Close
```

Comment: Magic...logic seems obvious really. Should have trusted myself rather than relying other people's logic. Thanks for your help JohnRC, much appreciated.